# php execute a python script from another directory

Tags: php, python, apache2, system

I have a PHP script that calls a Python script (with arguments):

```
<?php
$UPLOAD_DIR = 'tmp';
$AUDIOSPLIT = "../audiotranscri/scripts/audiospliter.py";
// This also fails using a symlink in the same dir
//$AUDIOSPLIT = "spliter";
$media_path = "tmp/media.mp3";
$subtitles_path = "tmp/mediasub.ass";

$cmd = "python3 ".$AUDIOSPLIT." ".$media_path." ".$subtitles_path." ".$UPLOAD_DIR;
echo($cmd);
system($cmd,$returnv);
echo($returnv);
?>
```

It works when i run this from a bash terminal

```
$ php7.2 dummy.php
```

But fails when  call it from a website (Apache2 with PHP). **Why ?**

N.B: I am sure Apache and PHP are running OK since phpinfo() works perfectly. Versions are PHP 7.2.15, ubuntu 18.04.1, Apache 2.4.29.

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: i would be using full path names, not relative ones in an application like this

Comment: there is no error message. I tried full paths did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying one of these:

use full path for your program as PATH might not be set when using system() - change "python3 " to "/usr/bin/python3 ", or wherever your python3 is.

Using another function, exec(), shell_exec(), passthrough()

Check if your web server allows you to run given functions when running through http, check in your php.ini, or check with php script accessed through http

```
<?php
$function_name = "system";
if ( function_exists($function_name) ) {
    echo "$function_name is enabled";
}
else {
    echo "$function_name is not enabled";
}
```